# Ignoring conditions if the value not present in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4], "color": ["blue","black", "black", "yellow","red","green","black","red"],
                   "age": [10,20,20,30,5,10,17,12], "Flag": [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0], "name":["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]})
```

I want to check few conditions and get subset like below:

```
id = 1
color = "black"
age = 20
flag = 0

mask1 = df["id"]==id
mask2 = df["color"]==color 
mask3 = df["age"]==age
mask4 = df["Flag"]==flag

print(df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3 & mask4])
```

Output:

```
    id  color   age Flag    name
1   1   black   20  0       B
2   1   black   20  0       C
```

Which works fine but there's one catch,

say `color = "orange"`

`orange` is not present in `color` column so I want to ignore color condition

so my code will be:

```
mask1 = df["id"]==1 
mask3 = df["age"]==20 
mask4 = df["Flag"]==0

print(df[mask1 & mask3 & mask4])
```

I know I can perform above operation using `if-else` blocks by checking `len` is 0 or not for particular condition but it would be very lengthy and not so efficient

eg.  `if len(df[df["color"]==color) == 0:`

I am looking for more efficient solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do it this way :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4], "color": ["blue","black", "black", "yellow","red","green","black","red"],
                   "age": [10,20,20,30,5,10,17,12], "Flag": [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0], "name":["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]})

id = 1
color = "black"
age = 20
flag = 0

mask1 = df["id"]==id
mask2 = df["color"]==color 
mask3 = df["age"]==age
mask4 = df["Flag"]==flag

print(df[(mask1 + ~mask1.any()) & (mask2 + ~mask2.any()) & (mask3 + ~mask3.any()) & (mask4 + ~mask4.any())])
```

Feel free to ask if it is not clear.

Comment: can you explain use of `+` operator ?

Comment: If color = 'orange', mask2 will be full of "False" so that "~mask2.any()" will return "True". Given that  False + True =  True (since False = 0 and True = 1), "mask1 + ~mask1.any()" will return a serie of "True" values. So, finally, the color won't be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```py
mask1 = (df["id"]==id if  (df['id']==id).sum() else 1)
....
```

and so on, 
this could raise an error though if all the conditions are ignored, you could add a True vector then to prevent that from happening, so you could do

```py
mask1 = (df["id"]==id if  (df['id']==id).sum() else np.ones(df["id"].shape).astype(bool)))
```

A more efficient way would be

```py
id = 1
color = "black"
age = 20
flag = 0
name = None
vector = pd.Series([id, color, age, flag, name], index=df.columns)
r = (vector==df)
df[r[r.columns[r.sum()>0]].min(axis=1)]
```

### Update : explaining the last line

doing `r.sum()` gives the number of `True` value on each column, so `r.columns[r.sum()>0]` gives us the columns that have at least one `True` value in them, and then the `.min(axis=1)` allows us to detect if there is any `False` in the row, as for pandas `True>False`, so it's a way to make the & condition on all of the columns. `r[r.columns[r.sum()>0]].min(axis=1)`is then a boolean series that we use afterwards to retrieve the rows we are interted in.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4], "color": ["blue","black", 
    "black", "yellow","red","green","black","red"],
    "age": [10,20,20,30,5,10,17,12], "Flag": [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0], "name": 
    ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]})

id = 1
color = "orange" # I changed this part to an example not present
age = 20
flag = 0

mask1 = df["id"] == id if id in df['id'].values else True
mask2 = df["color"] == color if color in df['color'].values else True
mask3 = df["age"] == age if age in df['age'].values else True
mask4 = df["Flag"] == flag if flag in df['Flag'].values else True
print(df[mask1 & mask2]) # I changed this example otherwise the mask2 isn't activated
```

```
Out[1]:
   id   color  age  Flag name
0   1    blue   10     1    A
1   1   black   20     0    B
2   1   black   20     0    C
3   1  yellow   30     1    D
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, here is a solution:

mask = 'black'

```
for x,i in zip(df['color'].str.contains(mask),df.index):
    if x:
        print(df['color'][i],df['id'][i],df['age'][i],df['Flag'][i])
    else:
        print(df['id'][i],df['age'][i],df['Flag'][i])
```

The output:

```
1 10 1
black 1 20 0
black 1 20 0
1 30 1
3 5 1
3 10 0
black 4 17 1
4 12 0
```

And mask = 'orange'

The output:

```
1 10 1
1 20 0
1 20 0
1 30 1
3 5 1
3 10 0
4 17 1
4 12 0
```

Comment: That was an example, It is possible that I may have to ignore more than one condition or sometime all the condition

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, if we use a dictionary we can use some clever filtering :

#### First create your dict : (your keys will need to match your column names)

```
dict_ = {'id' : 1,
'color' : "orange",
'age' : 20,
'Flag' :0}
```

#### Then we iterate over your dataframe by the key,value pairs, makes for fewer if statements.

```
d = {}
for k,v in dict_.items():
    if v in df[k].values:
       d[k] = v
     else:
        print(f"{k}: {v} not present in dataframe")
out: "color: orange not present in dataframe"
```

#### Then fitler your dataframe :

```
print(df.loc[(df[list(d)] == pd.Series(d)).all(axis=1)])

    id  color  age  Flag name
1   1  black   20     0    B
2   1  black   20     0    C
```

and if we `print(d)`

```
{'id': 1, 'age': 20, 'Flag': 0}
```

also, if no value is present in the dict it returns the entire dataframe.